# Изменить цвет текста в заголовке AlertDialog

Tags: android, color, android-dialog

Есть диалог `guidedialog`. Как изменить цвет его заголовка (`Title`) программно. А если нельзя программно, то как вообще можно?

```
final AlertDialog.Builder guidedialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    final View relativeLayout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.guide_1, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.textGuide);

    guidedialog.setTitle("Здравствуй!");
    guidedialog.setView(relativeLayout);

    textView.setText("Вы достигли своей цели. Вы можете прямо сейчас начать новую, или сделать это позже!");

    guidedialog.setPositiveButton("Понятно!",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    checkExp();

                    trueReset(mSqLiteDatabase);

                    getActivity().finish();

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
    textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#333"));

    guidedialog.create();
    guidedialog.show();
```

Comment: Код диалога покажите. Возможные варианты зависят от реализации диалога.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблему решил так, создал отдельный xml с текстовым полем нужного цвета и подключил в мой диалог через метод `setCustomView();`

Answer (score 4):

Вот так

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Тест");
AlertDialog d = builder.create();
int textViewId = d.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
TextView tv = (TextView) d.findViewById(textViewId);
tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
d.show();
```

Comment: Не заработало. tv - null. Почему так - не знаю... Что делать?

Comment: Какой AlertDialog вы используете? На каком устройстве тестируете?

Comment: Простой alertdialog с кнопками. Тестирую на своем устройстве Doogee X6 на андроиде 5.1. Проблему решил, нужен был метод setCustomTitle